# SQL Server trigger: Invalid object name 'inserted' in case sensitive database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I've got a SQL Server `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that populates values in my table. But when I run an insert statement, I get the error that

> Invalid object name 'inserted'

Now my database collation is set to be case sensitive, so I'm not sure whether the case of the 'inserted' is the cause, but I've tried inserted, INSERTED and Inserted.

My trigger look something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateID   
ON Personnel   
INSTEAD OF INSERT   
AS 
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)     
    DECLARE @NewID int = 100 --Will be auto generated

    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO Personnel (AutoID, Firstname, Surname)
                SELECT ' + CAST(@NewID AS nvarchar) + ', Firstname, Surname
                FROM inserted'  
    EXECUTE (@SQL) 
END
```

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL - that seems unnecessary here.

Comment: Not only unnecessary but the cause of the error...

Comment: Why are you inserting record in `Personnel` table on same table trigger? It will create  recursion.

Comment: The reason for the dynamic sql is that I also generating a list of column names so that I do not have to maintain the trigger when new columns are added to the table.  For simplicity I left that part out, but I notice that what what you are saying in that is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic SQL creates a new "context" where variables and tables in the calling code block may not be available.

It is not at all surprising that `inserted` is not available.  The simple solution is not to use dynamic SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Personnel (AutoID, Firstname, Surname)
    SELECT CAST(@NewID AS nvarchar(255)), Firstname, Surname
    FROM inserted;
```

Also note that whenever you use a character type, you should *always* use a length.  The default length varies by context.  When it is not long enough, then your code will have hard-to-find bugs.